# Helm upgrade - recreating unmodified deployments

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have two types of deployments in my project based on rolling strategy - "Recreate" and "RollingUpdate".

Every time, I run "helm upgrade" from pipeline, "RollingUpdate" deployments are not restarted unless there is a change in hemlchart (which is intended behavior).

But "Recreate" deployments are always recreated, even when unmodified.

Is there a way to tell helm/kubernetes that I want them recreated only if something changed?

Unfortunatelly, I cannot make them "RollingUpdate" because they are not safe to run in parall... so I need to wait for previous instance to exit.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  If nothing is modified, I'd expect Helm to not send the manifest to the cluster, and if it did, I'd expect Kubernetes to not act on it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have trouble isolating "minimal reproducible example" :( do you know how could I "debug" what is being sent to kubernetes by helm to be able to compare (because comparing "deployment" yaml file, I do not see differences :(

Comment: no resolution from my side found, we have moved it to rolling update combined with "initContainer" check script to prevent parallel run...